# image thumbnail from video laravel

Tags: laravel, image, image-processing, video

I would like to take a thumbnail out of a video which was uploaded to the server from the first seconds of the video, how it can be achived this with Laravel?

Is this achievable only with ffmpeg or is there some PHP script/module for laravel which can optain this?

Comment: Did you try [spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction)? From the documentation: *"The package can also generate derived images such as thumbnails for images, video's and pdf's. Once you've set up your model, they're easily accessible: `$newsItem->getMedia('images')->first()->getUrl('thumb');`"*.

Comment: thanks, will check that module out and get back :)